# Is it possible to user-define the percentages for lower/upper whisper in boxplot of PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot, statistics

According to Section 5.12.1 of [the manual of PGFPlots; Revision 1.13 (2016/01/06)](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), boxplot visualizes (see Page 472):

> Median is the 0.5–quantile of the input data.
>   Lower quartile is the 0.25–quantile of the input data.
>   Upper quartile is the 0.75–quartile of the input data.
>   ***Lower whisker*** is the smallest data value which is larger than lower quartile−1.5 · IQR where IQR is the “inter–quartile–range”, i.e. the difference between upper quartile and lower quartile.
>   ***Upper whisker*** is the largest data value which is smaller than upper quartile+1.5 · IQR.

However, I would like to show the minimum, 25th, 50th, 75th, and 99th percentages of the input data. The data larger than the 99th quantile are considered outliers.

> Is it possible to user-define the percentages (say, 99%) for lower/upper whisper in boxplot of PGFPlots?

*Note:* This can be done in *Mathematica*; see the [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108209/22068).

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[y=1cm]
    \addplot+[boxplot]
      table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
      data\\
      1\\ 2\\ 
      11\\ 12\\ 13\\ 14\\ 15\\ 
      16\\ 17\\ 18\\ 19\\ 20\\ 
      30\\ 35\\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge you can change the whisker calculation *only* by using

```
/pgfplots/boxplot/whisker range={⟨number⟩} %(initially 1.5)
```

You find the documentation on page 477 of the manual linked in your question. However, ⟨number⟩ is not a percentage. Whiskers are calculated using the upper/lower quartile +/- ⟨number⟩ times the inter-quartile-range with

> inter–quartile–range := upper quartile − lower quartile.

Hence the answer to your question is "no, the above is all you can do (as long as you do not want define the whisker values manually)".

Comment: If I define the whisker values manually, is there a way of calculating them (such as the min/max, the median) in pgfplots?

Comment: Do you mean _calculating_ like: 1) parse the input data, 2) do the math on the data, and 3) print the values? I guess there is nothing out of the box. However, there always is _a way_ (which I don't know). But it might be utterly complicated (or more complicated than 100 ctrl+c / ctrv+v 's to paste the data manually).