# How to fill the parameters of `boxplot prepared` with data from table using PGFPlots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, boxplot

I want to draw a boxplot using [`boxplot prepared`@ Page 469 of pgfplots-manual; v1.13](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf), with the values of `lower whisker`, `lower quartile`, `median`, `higher quartile`, and `higher whisker` from a data file.

The data file is as follows (without comments):

```
lower whisker     // the first row
lower quartile    // the second row
median            // the third row
higher quartile   // the fourth row
higher whisker    // the fifth row
outlier1          // followed by n outliers
outlier2
...
outliern
```

I can access the outliers using `skip coords between index={0}{4}`, but how can I access the data like `lower whisker` as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  y=1.5cm,
  skip coords between index={0}{4},  // skip the first five data
]
\addplot+[
boxplot prepared={
lower whisker= ,   // the first row
lower quartile= ,  // the second row
median= ,          // the third row
upper quartile= ,  // the fourth row
upper whisker= ,   // the fifth row
},
]
table[y index=0] {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

***Note 1:*** This question is inspired by the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303086/23098) to the [post: Is it possible to user-define the percentages for lower/upper whisper in boxplot of PGFPlots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/295618/23098)

***Note 2:*** The *related post* [Read boxplot prepared values from a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117435/23098) assumes a different data format. I cannot figure out how to apply the techniques in that post to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transpose your table using `\pgfplotstabletranspose` and then use the solution given in [Read boxplot prepared values from a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117435/23098)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    boxplot prepared from table/.code={
        \def\tikz@plot@handler{\pgfplotsplothandlerboxplotprepared}%
        \pgfplotsset{
            /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
            #1,
        }
    },
    /pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/.cd,
        table/.code={\pgfplotstablecopy{#1}\to\boxplot@datatable},
        row/.initial=0,
        make style readable from table/.style={
            #1/.code={
                \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/boxplot prepared from table/row}}{##1}\of\boxplot@datatable
                \pgfplotsset{boxplot/#1/.expand once={\pgfplotsretval}}
            }
        },
        make style readable from table=lower whisker,
        make style readable from table=upper whisker,
        make style readable from table=lower quartile,
        make style readable from table=upper quartile,
        make style readable from table=median,
        make style readable from table=lower notch,
        make style readable from table=upper notch
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.txt}
5   4
7   5
8.5 6.5
9.5 8.5
10  9.5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to=]{\datatable}{data.txt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[boxplot/draw direction=y]
  \addplot+[
  boxplot prepared from table={
    table=\datatable,
    lower whisker=0,
    upper whisker=4,
    lower quartile=1,
    upper quartile=3,
    median=2
  }, boxplot prepared
  ]
  coordinates {};

  \addplot+[
  boxplot prepared from table={
    table=\datatable,
    row=1,
    lower whisker=0,
    upper whisker=4,
    lower quartile=1,
    upper quartile=3,
    median=2
  }, boxplot prepared
  ]
  coordinates {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```